# Nested loop it sound start all over, from 1 and count up. But it dont

Tags: java, loops, nested

Hi guys i am trying to make a nested loop, where the loop in the first loop should start all over again instead off repeating 161. As you can see at the picture it fails. And i dont know how to fix it.

Here is an exsample of my code and i have left a comment in the code where it fails:

```
    int category_a = 1;
    String childname_a = "A";

    int category_b = 2;
    String childname_b = "B";

    int category_c = 3;
    String childname_c = "C";

    String description = "Indsæt beskrivelse her";


    try

    {

        db.beginTransaction();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO child (_idchild, category, childname, description) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement(sql);



        for (int i = 1; i < 162; i++)
        {
                statement.clearBindings();
                statement.bindLong(1, i);
                statement.bindLong(2, category_a); //+ i
                statement.bindString(3, childname_a + i);
                statement.bindString(4, description);
                statement.executeInsert();

        }


        for (int j = 162; j < 325; j++)
        {
            statement.clearBindings();
            statement.bindLong(1, j);
            statement.bindLong(2, category_b); //+ i

             // It fails here, and do not start from 1 and count up to 162 as you can see.
            for (int h = 1; h < 162; h++)
            {
                statement.bindString(3, childname_b + h);
            }

            statement.bindString(4, description);
            statement.executeInsert();
        }





            db.setTransactionSuccessful(); // This commits the transaction if there were no exceptions

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.w("Exception:", e);
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
```

[the b section should start from 1 and go up, but et fails at repeating 161 as you can see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBQjB.png)

Comment: This line doesn't make sense to me. `statement.bindString(3, childname_b + h);`. It will overwrite the value in each iteration finally setting it to 161 as it should be. Perhaps you can tell us if there are more columns where you want to bind these variables.

Comment: Remove the inner for loop and change it to `statement.bindString(3, childname_b + j);` instead as done in first for loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you want records B1 to B162 for every j then it is the following. Possibly it is sufficient to bind description before the inner loop and only bind string 3 and execute insert in the loop

```
for (int j = 162; j < 325; j++)
{
    for (int h = 1; h < 162; h++)
    {
        statement.clearBindings();
        statement.bindLong(1, j);
        statement.bindLong(2, category_b); //+ i
        statement.bindString(3, childname_b + h);
        statement.bindString(4, description);
        statement.executeInsert();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are missing a `statement.executeInsert();` in the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
        for (int j = 162; j < 325; j++)
        {
            statement.clearBindings();
            statement.bindLong(1, j);
            statement.bindLong(2, category_b); //+ i
            statement.bindString(3, childname_b + j);
            statement.bindString(4, description);
            statement.executeInsert();
        }
```